# Why constructor function can't access property of his prototype, but can access property of parent prototype (prototype of prototype)

Tags: javascript

Following code, i checked using chrome browser console :

```
function A(){
  this.a='a'
}
```

this is a constructor function.i have assined a property `b` to the prototype of `A`.

```
A.prototype.b='b';
```

but when i access `b` property using constructor function `A`. it is showing `undefined`.

```
A.b //it return undefined
```

again i assigned property `m`to the `Function.prototype`, and the access using `A` it return coorect vaue.

```
Function.prototype.m='m';
A.m //it return "m"
```

So why **constructor function can't access his prototype property,but can access parent prototype (protype of his prototype) property**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot access it as `A.b` since `A` is not an instance of `A` constructor. You need to:

```
var instanceA = new A();
instanceA.b; // will work
```

Whereas

```
Function.prototype.m='m';
A.m //it return "m"
```

does work because `A` is an instance of the `Function` object.

Answer (score 2):

You can't access `A.prototype.b` because you haven't instantiated `A`. Prototypes are objects which are [created during the instantiation of an Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/prototype). In your example, here's how this might look:

```
// Create your constructor and prototype object
function A() {}
A.prototype = {
  b: "b"
};

var a = new A();
console.log(a.b); 
>>> "b"
```

However, in the case of `A.m`, `A` (note, capital A, your constructor), *is* an instance of `Function`, and so inherits all of it's attributes, including the one you've added.

For more, I suggest you look at the MDN article on an [introduction to Object-Oriented JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Introduction_to_Object-Oriented_JavaScript)